# Can I query history of my SEDE queries?

Tags: support, data-explorer

**Is there a way to query my SEDE saved queries or query history?**

I could scrape the list from `https://data.stackexchange.com/users/{SEDE User#}/?order_by=recent&page={PAGE#}` (in my case, 350 pages/5000 revisions) but figured I should see if the data is stored somewhere *query-able...*

I could "search" but that doesn't include the SQL "body" unless the query has no title, in which case the first 60 characters of SQL are used as the title.

Are the saved queries stored on an SE server or elsewhere?

Answer (score 3):

No, unfortunately you can't.

Technically they are saved in the database `[data.stackexchange]` but as that database also contains the users and their IP addresses the database is secured. Accessing it gives

> The server principal "STACKEXCHANGE\svc_sede" is not able to access the database "Data.StackExchange" under the current security context.

It would need a feature request to access that data, where I think it is preferable to have some API end-point as I don't think Nick fancies adding an accessible view. But these details are better discussed and ironed out in said feature request.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I can't imagine there would be enough demand to add this functionality. For now I've slapped together an Excel workbook to scrape a list of my own saved queries.